# Getting hold of raw POST data when using [FromBody]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller running on ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 and I'd like to dump the raw POST data out to telemetry as ApplicationInsights doesn't do this for you. My code looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] RequestClass RequestData)
{
    var stream = this.HttpContext.Request.Body;
    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Telemetry.TrackTrace(body, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

But the string "body" always comes up empty. If I remove the [FromBody] decoration from the function signature, then this code works, but the RequestData object only contains null, which isn't what I want.

The only thing I can think of is converting RequestData back to a Json string, but this feels clunky and slow.

(EDIT: The POST data is Json)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as you were. Can you post what your fix was?

Comment: As mentioned in Tratchers answer below, I used EnableRewind

`app.Use((context, next) => { context.Request.EnableRewind(); return next(); });`

Comment: I see.. Might be worth it to add that to your question as his answer is about the `BufferBody` and the Enable rewind bit is only in the comments. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure of the etiquette here as I didn't want to take credit for his answer by adding a new answer that just had that.

Comment: Understandable.. Perhaps you edit your original question to include a disclaimer that the final solution you used is in the comments of his answer.

Comment: Also, that does seem to work for me as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable buffering the request body:
`services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => options.BufferBody = true);`
https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/FormOptions.cs#L20

Comment: Thanks, that works for my endpoints that use forms, but unfortunately doesn't work for endpoints that take Json as post data. Is there an equivalent for non-form requests?
I looked through the github you linked to, and can't see anything.

Comment: I looked through the code to work out what BufferBody was doing, and based on that I tried adding
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.EnableRewind(this.HttpContext.Request);`
But this doesn't seem to fix the issue.
(Yes, I know I shouldn't access Internal namespaces, but just wanted to know if it would work)

Comment: EnableRewind could work, but you'd have to call it before MVC.

Comment: app.Use((context, next) => { context.Request.EnableRewind(); return next(); });

Answer (score 4):

The most simple way I found to solve this issue is to use **jObject** as the Model.
And send the request with **Content-Type: application/json** at the header.

Use something like NewtonSoft's json dll this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] jObject RequestData)
{
    string str = RequestData["key"];
    return Ok();
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The request stream has already been read, so what you can do here is **EnableRewind** on the Request

[See solution here for reading json from body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561350/read-json-post-data-in-asp-net-core-mvc). Same should apply to your issue.