# Read JSON post data in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I've tried to find a solution for this, but all the ones coming up are for previous versions of ASP.Net.

I'm working with the JWT authentication middleware and have the following method:

```
private async Task GenerateToken(HttpContext context)
{
    var username = context.Request.Form["username"];
    var password = context.Request.Form["password"];
    //Remainder of login code
}
```

This gets the sent data as if it was form data, but my Angular 2 front end is sending the data as JSON.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
        return this.http.post(this._api.apiUrl + 'token', body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                
            });
    }
```

My preferred solution is to send it as JSON, but I've been unsuccessful in retrieving the data.  I know it's sending, because I can see it in fiddler, and if I use Postman and just send form data it works fine.

Basically I just need to figure out how to change this line to read the json data

```
var username = context.Request.Form["username"];
```

Comment: why don't you just switch you login function to use Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and just url encode the json

Comment: I would like the entire front end to be able to send json rather than having some use json and some use form data.  I did actually try this route though and was having a hard time getting the data to send correctly as form data.  Even with examples I couldn't get the two to talk to each other correctly.

Comment: shouldn't you just be able to do this? `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }));`

Comment: No, it's more complicated than that.

Comment: After struggling with both routes I figured the easiest fix was to figure out how to get at that json data.

Comment: I'm working with IdentityServer4 and as far as I can tell it does the same thing, which is very annoying Id prefer json as well.  If I find an answer I'll let you know

Answer (score 13):

By the time it gets to your middleware the request stream has already been read, so what you can do here is **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.EnableRewind** on the **Request** and read it yourself

Site wide :

```
Startup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;

Startup.Configure(...){
...
//Its important the rewind us added before UseMvc
app.Use(next => context => { context.Request.EnableRewind(); return next(context); });
app.UseMvc()
...
}
```

OR selective :

```
private async Task GenerateToken(HttpContext context)
    {
     context.Request.EnableRewind();
     string jsonData = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `EnableRewind` in both your middleware and in your `GenerateToken` method?

Comment: With the second option you have to add `context.Request.Body.Position = 0;` between those two lines. Otherwise the reader returns an empty string because the server had already reached the end of the body on its own.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the 2nd option as is and not hitting that issue. Based on net core 1.1

Comment: In .Net Core 2 I had to add `context.Request.Body.Position = 0;` *after* the `StreamReader` otherwise my Post's were getting empty Body.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 5 there is an intentional breaking change to avoid the usage of internal methods. Then new API is EnableBuffering

So use           context.Request.EnableBuffering();
Instead of      context.Request.EnableRewind();

More info:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22382#issuecomment-636275214