# Compare the Hash of a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, api, hash, .net-core

I am attempting to get a hash comparer to work so I can validate an incoming request.

Flow:
`Sender creates json object` -> `sender creates hash of json object with a key that they and I know` -> `sender sends json object and header with hash in it` -> `I recieve request` -> `I hash the json object with the common key` -> `I compare my hash to the one in the header to validate user sending it`

I am struggling to create a hash from my json object.

This is the example code in Ruby (from the sender) where `request_payload` is JSON object.

```
hmac=OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'),YOUR_COMPANY_SIGNING_KEY,request_payload)  
signature = Base64.strict_encode64(hmac)
```

I want to do this **in C#**.

I am using the data from [the Call Rail API](https://apidocs.callrail.com/#validating-payloads) (see right side) and attempting to hash it into string and then encode it.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync(dynamic request)
{

    string signature = GetHash(request.ToString(), "072e77e426f92738a72fe23c4d1953b4"); // this key is from the example in Call Rail

    string encodedSignature = Base64Encode(signature);

    return Ok();
}

public static String GetHash(dynamic text, String key)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    Byte[] textBytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    Byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    Byte[] hashBytes;

    using (HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(textBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

I think where I am struggling is how I can take my incoming JSON

```
{"answered":false,"business_phone_number":"","call_type":"voicemail","company_id":155920786,"company_name":"Boost Marketing","company_time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","created_at":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.252-05:00","customer_city":"Rochester","customer_country":"US","customer_name":"Kaylah Mills","customer_phone_number":"+12148654559","customer_state":"PA","device_type":"","direction":"inbound","duration":"13","first_call":false,"formatted_call_type":"Voicemail","formatted_customer_location":"Rochester, PA","formatted_business_phone_number":"","formatted_customer_name":"Kaylah Mills","prior_calls":16,"formatted_customer_name_or_phone_number":"Kaylah Mills","formatted_customer_phone_number":"214-865-4559","formatted_duration":"13s","formatted_tracking_phone_number":"404-555-8514","formatted_tracking_source":"Google Paid","formatted_value":"--","good_lead_call_id":715587840,"good_lead_call_time":"2016-06-17T10:23:33.363-04:00","id":766970532,"lead_status":"previously_marked_good_lead","note":"","recording":"https://app.callrail.com/calls/766970532/recording/redirect?access_key=aaaaccccddddeeee","recording_duration":8,"source_name":"Google AdWords","start_time":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.236-05:00","tags":[],"total_calls":17,"tracking_phone_number":"+14045558514","transcription":"","value":"","voicemail":true,"tracker_id":354024023,"keywords":"","medium":"","referring_url":"","landing_page_url":"","last_requested_url":"","referrer_domain":"","conversational_transcript":"","utm_source":"google","utm_medium":"cpc","utm_term":"","utm_content":"","utm_campaign":"Google AdWords","utma":"","utmb":"","utmc":"","utmv":"","utmz":"","ga":"","gclid":"","integration_data":[{"integration":"Webhooks","data":null}],"keywords_spotted":"","recording_player":"https://app.callrail.com/calls/766970532/recording?access_key=aaaabbbbccccdddd","speaker_percent":"","call_highlights":[],"callercity":"Rochester","callercountry":"US","callername":"Kaylah Mills","callernum":"+12148654559","callerstate":"PA","callsource":"google_paid","campaign":"","custom":"","datetime":"2018-02-19 18:41:00","destinationnum":"","ip":"","kissmetrics_id":"","landingpage":"","referrer":"","referrermedium":"","score":1,"tag":"","trackingnum":"+14045558514","timestamp":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.236-05:00"}
```

And then be able to Hash it into something useful.

With the test signing key I am given, I should get back `UZAHbUdfm3GqL7qzilGozGzWV64=`. I know this from the [APIDocs](https://apidocs.callrail.com/#validating-payloads).

I am currently sending up the JSON string above via postman but I notice that extra '`{` `}`' are added on when I treat it as datatype `dynamic` or `object`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two different requests could be equivalent (i.e. 'effectively' the same JSON) but one has spaces in it that the other doesn't. Do you expect them to have the same hash value?

Comment: I think the extra `{` and `}` are just being "helpfully" added by the debugger as some sort of debugger visualization.  More likely your incoming request was parsed into a `JToken`, then when re-serialized via `ToString()` formatting was added.  To serialize without formatting do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)`, then see if that works.

Comment: But note that, according to the [JSON standard](https://json.org/), a JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs* so using string hashes on JSON is a little iffy since permuting the property order ought not to change the hash.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Getting hold of raw POST data when using `[FromBody]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37839907).

Comment: @mjwills Yes I do expect them to have the same value. I am expecting to be sent json and then a header with a hash of a key that the sender and I share. We can assume confidence that the sender with be hashing with the same json they are sending.

Comment: OK - given you are expecting the same hash code for two different strings, it seems to me that you can't generate the hash based on the string. I suspect you need to convert the string to some form of object representation and generate a hash based on that. Or, alternatively, normalise the JSON somehow to ensure that excess whitespace etc is removed before hashing.

Comment: @mjwills I am expecting the "string" (the json sent) to be the same

Comment: @dbc I have added further explanation at the top of my question. I hope that clears it up more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is that the .NET Core WebAPI is helpfully parsing the body into JSON (into a `JObject`) for you.

As @dbc identified, really what you need is the raw string body to use to generate the HMAC Signature, which you can verify before parsing the body into JSON yourself.

I tested [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47807117/130641) and was able to receive the body as a plain string:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;

namespace netcoretest {
    public class RawJsonBodyInputFormatter : InputFormatter
    {
        public RawJsonBodyInputFormatter()
        {
            this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/json");
        }

        public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
            }
        }

        protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(string);
        }
    }
}
```

in **Startup.cs:**

```cs
// in ConfigureServices()
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawJsonBodyInputFormatter());
});
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostTest([FromBody]string request)
{
  // here request is now the request body as a plain string;
  // you can now compute the signature on it and then later parse it to JSON.


}
```

However, testing your current code to generate the Base64-encoded signature, I am not getting the correct signature:

1. you are converting the output of the HMAC to hexadecimal string, and then taking the bytes of that string and putting those into your Base64 encoding.  The sample ruby you linked returns plain bytes, not a hexadecimal string from `HMAC.digest`:

```rb
[5] pry(main)> hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), YOUR_COMPANY_SIGNING_KEY, s)
=> "Q\x90\amG_\x9Bq\xAA/\xBA\xB3\x8AQ\xA8\xCCl\xD6W\xAE"
```

So at least that portion needs to be corrected in your implementation as well.

**Update**

I was able to get the correct signature with the following code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace netcoretest.Controllers
{
    [Route("test")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        public TestController()
        {
        }

        // POST: /test
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostTest([FromBody]string request)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            Byte[] key = encoding.GetBytes("072e77e426f92738a72fe23c4d1953b4");
            HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(key);
            Byte[] bytes = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(request));
            Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(bytes));
            String result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            return Ok();
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-","");
        }
    }
}
```

I tested posting to this endpoint using the following:

```
url --request POST https://localhost:5001/test --insecure --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @test.json
```

where `test.json` is the sample JSON blob from the API Documentation.

If using this same code you cannot get the signature to match, double check that your `test.json` does not have any trailing newlines or whitespace.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @john_Ledbetter thanks for the answer! I will try it right away. As for the encoding, I was only doing that because of the `Base64.strict_encode64(hmac)` from the Ruby implimentation. Do I not need to do that?

Comment: You do need to base64 encode the results, but you _don't_ need to convert the HMAC bytes to a hexadecimal string prior to encoding as base64.

Comment: @thalacker I've updated this answer with the full controller which generates a signature matching the sample signature.

Comment: I understand much better now. Thank you for your thorough explaination

Answer (score 1):

Though @john_Ledbetter 's answer works great, I decided an action filter fit me better. So I used his answer as a base and modified it for me. I don't believe this solution would need the InputFormatter

`ValidateCallRailRequestFiler.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My_API.ActionFilters
{
    public class ValidateCallRailRequestFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        //private readonly ILogger<ValidateCallRailRequestFilter> _logger;
        //public ValidateCallRailRequestFilter(ILogger<ValidateCallRailRequestFilter> logger)
        //{
        //    _logger = logger;
        //}

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
        {
            //executing before action is called

            // this should only return one object since that is all an API allows. Also, it should send something else it will be a bad request
            var param = actionContext.ActionArguments.SingleOrDefault();
            if (param.Value == null)
            {
                //_logger.LogError("Object sent was null. Caught in ValidateCallRailRequestFilter class.");
                actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Object sent is null");
                return;
            }

            var context = actionContext.HttpContext;
            if (!IsValidRequest(context.Request))
            {
                actionContext.Result = new ForbidResult();
                return;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        }

        private static bool IsValidRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            string json = GetRawBodyString(request.HttpContext);
            string token = "072e77e426f92738a72fe23c4d1953b4"; // this is the token that the API (Call Rail) would provide
            string signature = request.Headers["Signature"];

            // validation for comparing encoding to bytes and hashing to be the same
            //https://rextester.com/EBR67249

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] key = encoding.GetBytes(token);
            HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(key);
            byte[] bytes = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(json));

            string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);            

            return signature.Equals(result, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public static string GetRawBodyString(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var body = "";
            if (httpContext.Request.ContentLength == null || !(httpContext.Request.ContentLength > 0) ||
                !httpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek) return body;
            httpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
            httpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

This includes a body reader that reads in the JSON and a way to deny incoming requests that don't match the signature as 403 forbidden.

Then within my controller:

```
[ValidateCallRailRequestFilter]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync(dynamic request)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

with a `using My_Api.ActionFilters;`

And then I hit it with postman.
[image: note that it is not "beautified"]
[image: note the header here]